# Featured products on the homepage disappeared

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-connect, featured-product

Featured products on the homepage disappeared after upgrading all packages through Magento connect.

I've cleared all the caches and reindexed the site but the problem still persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check in `var/log/system.log` file

I think it's just because of **SUPEE 6788** error. You need to allow that block to be displayed.